# Java separar palabra en caracteres usando arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

```
  int intentos = 6;
        ArrayList<Character> palabrita = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Character> palabras_dichas = new ArrayList<>();



        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del Jugador 1");
            System.out.print("-->");
            j1 = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del Jugador 2");
            System.out.print("-->");
            j2 = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(j1+" : Introduce la palabra a adivinar para "+j2);
            System.out.print("-->");
            palabra = br.readLine();



            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
                palabrita.get(i) = palabra.charAt(i);
            }
```

Ese ultimo `for` que es para despedazar la palabra en un `array` de `char` . No sé porque no funciona eso, es lo mas simple del mundo y no sé que pasa

Comment: el fallo que me da esta en el 'for'

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la siguiente sentencia:

```
    palabrita.get(i) = palabra.charAt(i);
```

Quieres asignar el valor de `palabra.charAt(i)` a la posición `i` del ArrayList, sin embargo en una asignacion se espera que el lado izquierdo sea una variable, no un valor, por lo tanto obtendrás el siguiente error de compilacion:

```
unexpected type

palabrita.get(i) = palabra.charAt(i);
                ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

La manera de agregar un elemento a un ArrayList es mediante el método [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)), por lo que la forma correcta de hacer lo que quieres es:

```
palabrita.add(palabra.charAt(i))
```

Por otro lado, no es necesario que iteres sobre los caracteres de `palabra` para obtener un array de caracteres, puedes utilizar el método de la clase String [toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()):

```
char [] palabrita = palabra.toCharArray();
```

Comment: "Supongo que estas obteniendo NullPointerException y eso sucede en la siguiente sentencia" en realidad debería obtener un error de compilación. Esa sentencia nunca compilará.

Answer (score 0):

no me quedó muy claro cual es la pregunta. Por lo que entendí queres pasar un string a un array de chars?. Si eso es lo que querés hacer aquí te paso una posible solución:

```
public char[] charString(String palabra){
  char [] charsPalabra = new char[palabra.length()];
  for(int i = 0; i< palabra.length(); i++){
      charsPalabra [i] = palabra.charAt(i);
  }
  return charsPalabra;
}
```

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Saludos!